# log2 issue when doing Survival Analysis

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am planning to use TCGAbiolinks to perform an survival analysis by using the following code:

```
library(TCGAbiolinks)
library(SummarizedExperiment)
query_RNAseq <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-PAAD",
                         data.category = "Gene expression",
                         data.type = "Gene expression quantification",
                         platform = "Illumina HiSeq", 
                         file.type  = "results",
                         experimental.strategy = "RNA-Seq",
                         legacy = TRUE)
GDCdownload(query_RNAseq, method = "api",chunks.per.download = 10) 
PAADRnaseqSE <- GDCprepare(query_RNAseq)

# Survival Analysis SA
clinical_patient_Cancer <- GDCquery_clinic("TCGA-PAAD","clinical")
dataPAADcomplete <- log2(PAADRnaseqSE)
```

but it produced an error when I run the log2 function, code and error info are pasted below

```
> dataPAADcomplete <- log2(PAADRnaseqSE)
Error in log(<S4 object of class "RangedSummarizedExperiment">, 2) : 
  unused argument (2)
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: where does the code come from?  What did you expect the last line to do? `log2()` works on numbers, whereas `PADDRnaseSE` is a complex data structure ...

Comment: Just a guess, but does `log2(as.numeric(PAADRnaseqSE))` work?

Comment: @Ben Bolkeryes, thank you, I solved the problem after I turn `PAADRnaseqSE` into matrix by using the assay function from SummarizedExperiment package:`PAADMatrix <- assay(PAADRnaseqSE,"raw_count")`

Comment: @ Mist,it doesn't work, but I have solve the problem. Thank you for the tip